# Socket.io using Using Node.JS Cluster with PM2

Tags: node.js, socket.io, pm2

I have tried, https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/

```
const io = require('socket.io')(3000);
const redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
```

but didn't work, with multiple core of server. Can anyone expert here will guilde me will appreciated by me.

I using PM2 for node process clustering.

and i am facing issue, user in different thread could no connect with socket.IO but all users in same Socket.IO thread connection is working fine.

In short I want to cluster multiple Socket.IO server for Load balancing.

Comment: Can you add a bit more explanation? Which load-balancer are you using? what is the config? what is the desire state?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As Daniel asked, can you provide the errors you encountered and more details on how your system is set up? Check out these docs on improving questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: so your installing redis on each node?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone what after installing redis for each niode?

Comment: if a user connects to server A, `localhost` is server A, it wont be picking up from server B, C or D's redis instances

Comment: @LawrenceCherone could you please explain in detail?

Comment: [here's a diagram](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/9c96c7b0d20fc0f3ba6404ad1535e33821c9315f/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f666c6f636b6f6e75732f6761727473622f6d61737465722f646f63732f6f766572766965775f736368656d612e706e67), socket.io instances talk to a single redis instance (or load-balanced) to pick up on a global session for all clients.. the localhost used in the example on socketio website is to get it working for multiple processes not multiple servers

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks it clear for me but how to set single redis instance for all socket.io servers